How to write a solver for the vibration ODE using the current version of Devito?
I'm reading the devito_book/fdm-jupyter-book/notebooks/01_vib/vib_undamped.ipynb and the code in it seems not compatible with devito 4.8.3.
So I tried to rewrite it as:
import numpy as np
from devito import Constant, TimeFunction, Eq, solve, Operator, Grid, TimeDimension


def solver(I, w, dt, T):
    dt = float(dt)
    Nt = int(round(T / dt))
    t = TimeDimension('t', spacing=Constant('h_t'))
    grid = Grid(shape=(Nt + 1, ), time_dimension=t)
    u = TimeFunction(name='u', grid=grid, time_order=2)

    u.data[:] = I
    eqn = u.dt2 + w ** 2 * u
    stencil = Eq(u.forward, solve(eqn, u.forward))
    op = Operator(stencil)
    op.apply(h_t=dt, t_M=Nt - 1)
    return u.data, np.linspace(0, Nt * dt, Nt + 1)


I = 1
w = 2 * np.pi
dt = 0.05
num_periods = 5
P = 2 * np.pi / w
T = P * num_periods
u, t = solver(I, w, dt, T)

However, the data of returned u is:
[[0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113,  0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113 0.95374113], [1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983,  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983  1.0121983 ], [0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535,  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535  0.8011535 ]]

The value does not update from one time node to the next. Could anyone help me solve this issue?
Thank you in advance!

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from devito import Constant, TimeFunction, Eq, solve, Operator, Grid, TimeDimension


def solver(I, w, dt, T):
    dt = float(dt)
    Nt = int(round(T / dt))
    t = TimeDimension('t', spacing=Constant('h_t'))
    grid = Grid(shape=(2, ), time_dimension=t)
    u = TimeFunction(name='u', grid=grid, time_order=2, save=Nt + 1)

    u.data[0:] = I
    u.data[1:] = (1 - 0.5 * dt ** 2 * w ** 2) * I
    eqn = u.dt2 + w ** 2 * u
    stencil = Eq(u.forward, solve(eqn, u.forward))
    op = Operator(stencil)
    op.apply(h_t=dt, t_M=Nt - 1)
    return np.array(u.data)[:, 0], np.linspace(0, Nt * dt, Nt + 1)


def u_exact(t, I, w):
    return I * np.cos(w * t)


def visualize(u, t, I, w):
    plt.plot(t, u, 'r--o')
    t_fine = np.linspace(0, t[-1], 1001)
    u_e = u_exact(t_fine, I, w)
    plt.plot(t_fine, u_e, 'b-')
    plt.legend(['numerical', 'exact'], loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel('t')
    plt.ylabel('u')
    dt = t[1] - t[0]
    plt.title('dt=%g' % dt)
    umin = 1.2 * u.min()
    umax = -umin
    plt.axis((t[0], t[-1], umin, umax))
    plt.savefig('tmp.png')
    plt.savefig('tmp.pdf')


I = 1
w = 2 * np.pi
dt = 0.05
num_periods = 5
P = 2 * np.pi / w
T = P * num_periods
u, t = solver(I, w, dt, T)
visualize(u, t, I, w)

Result
